# Не срабатывает Input для строки

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Почему не считывается вводимая строка?
С числами работает, если добавить sval, а со строками никак.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
  include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
_mov db "test ",0
 .code 

 start: 

 invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 

    push eax
    mov eax, input() ; <========== Вот тут вся проблема
    mov _mov, eax ; И тут тоже
    pop eax

 Main endp 
 end start
```

Вот то на чём я остановился...

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
  include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
    ;includelib C:\masm32\lib\winextra.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
 hmyHeap dd 0
 nim dd ?
_mov db "test",0
hMylp1 dd 0
 .code 

 start: 

 invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
 invoke GetProcessHeap
 mov hmyHeap,eax

invoke HeapAlloc,hmyHeap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,300h
mov hMylp1,eax

;mov edx, sizeof _mov
;invoke RtlMoveMemory,eax,addr _mov, edx

    push eax

    mov ebx, input()
    mov edx, sizeof (ebx)
    ;mov _mov, eax
    pop eax

mov ebx, [hMylp1]
invoke HeapFree,hmyHeap,NULL,hMylp1

 Main endp 
 end start
```

Ну вот посмотрите вроде-бы всё работает, как вы думаете правильно? Если правильно то в eax у меня адрес на строчку или значение уже?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас те макросы, которые выдал мне гугл, то input вводит строку ascii символов с клавиатуры в указанный буфер. http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/MLabs/M08console/lecture.html  После чего вам надо эти ascii символы уже конвертировать в число, которое потом и использовать. А вторая инструкция ... у вас _mov (и зачем вы только так называете переменную, что означает это имя ?) он у вас DB - строка байтов причем этих байтов более 4х и вы хотите в эти байты загрузить значние из четырехбайтового регистра. И вам надо обязательно понять разницу между текстовыми строками и двоичными данными в регистах

Comment: @Mike то есть вы имеете ввиду что нужно создавать heap и туда всё пихать?

Comment: А причем тут heap, вы можете буфер под строку и в сегменте данных сделать если он небольшой и фиксированного размера. Если хотите ввести число в десятичной системе для последующего использования как 32 битного числа - то вам надо то всего 11 байт. Кстати по ссылке что я дал они прямо в примере к input так и делают

Comment: @Mike а у меня может быть введено от пару букв до пару предложений (

Comment: Вам место в сегменте данных жалко ? сделайте 255 символов, да хоть килобайт, не хватит ?  И интересно как вы в eax собирались такую строку поместить

Comment: Хотя конечно злоупотреблять то же не стоит, сегмент данных занимает свое место в exe файле. А heap не занимает.

Comment: @Mike вот почему я и сказал что в heap лучше кидать текст, потому-что потом в нём можно делать : добавлять строку к строке, удалять подстроку, менять размеры и т.д. а самое что по кайфу, то что heap большой и туда можно большие тексты запихивать.

Comment: @Mike помогите пожалуйста как строку из input сразу переправить в heap, если что тему обновил

Comment: Судя по написанному в той ссылке, что в начале давал, тупо `input hMylp1, 2FEh` ну или сколько вы там хотите вводить символов. хотя может надо сначала в регистр загрузить указатель и передать регистр, иначе как макрос поймет что надо взять не адрес указанной переменной, а адрес лежищий в этой переменной. Но вообще это вы в доке на свой masm смотрите как должны работать эти макросы.

Comment: @Mike а как мне проверить что текст записался в heap?
 mov [hMylp1], input()
Если что под рукой есть ollydbg

Comment: Я на асме писал 15 лет назад и таких крутых макросов тогда в помине не было, все руками делали. И отладчиков, которые сейчас в виндах есть так же не существовало. В общем виде - загрузить в отладчик дойти до строки выполнившей input и посмотреть в памяти.

Comment: @Mike посмотрите пожалуйста в конец темы, тему обновил

Comment: С виду все ок. правда смысла в mov eax,dword ptr ... особого не видно. Вы в регистр eax загружаете первые 4 символа строки

Comment: @Mike не, я делаю mov eax, [hMylp1] для того чтобы посмотреть что храниться в heap перекинув его толи значение, толи адрес в eax, мне просто проще регистр посмотреть чем heap, тем более я не знаю как его просматривать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
 addrHeap dd 0
 hMylp1 dd 0
 .code 

 start: 

 invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
 invoke GetProcessHeap
 mov addrHeap,eax

 invoke HeapAlloc,addrHeap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,300h
 mov hMylp1,eax
 mov [hMylp1], input()
 mov eax, [hMylp1]
 invoke HeapFree,hmyHeap,NULL,hMylp1

 Main endp 
 end start
```